# writing a grid that has both column and row virtualization

Tags: wpf, grid, virtualization

I need to write an excel-like grid that can have a lot of cells (400x400). All columns have the same width and all rows the same height. Each cell can contain text or be empty and each cell can have a column **and/or row** span. I suppose this will never work with the [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) panel and I suppose I will need UI virtualization in both column and row direction.

So my first try was to create a virtualizing grid by deriving from [VirtualizingPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.aspx) and implement [IScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx). This could have "easily" be the solution except that I ran into a problem:

To provide `IScrollInfo` with the relevant information about scroll size and position and to be able to detemine wich items need to be created (realized) next using the ItemsContainerGenerator, I need to know the column index, row indeox and columnspan for each child item (cell). The only way I can think of to do this is using attach properties. The problem is: I can only read the values of attached properties if the  ItemContainer that has them is already realized. So I am in a catch 22 here. To know what to realize I need to realize all items. To provide the data for `IScrollInfo` I need to realize all items.

So it seems that I am at a dead end with this approach.

Do you have any idea how I could implement a control like this or know how I could reslove the above problem?

Comment: You mention that each row has the same height and each column the same width. It seems like it would be possible to do calculations to calculate the scroll data. Can you explain further why this is presenting a challenge?

Comment: Yes calculating the scroll data could be done. The problem: anywhere in the grid there can be cells with arbitary column and/or rowspan. I have update my question. So when scrolling, sometimes a cell does not fully fit into the current viewport. Additionally I was hoping to utilize the virtualization techniques in that a cell can have item datatemplates with bindings to the viewmodel for the cells that get realized only when it comes into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strikes me that you may not need to instanciate the UI elements themselves- you can very easily have a collection of DependencyObject-derived viewmodels, each of which has the WidthProperty and HeightProperty set (and possibly bound to the equivalent Width and Height properties of the visible cell UI element, once those are created).

Storing 160,000 (400x400) class instances shouldn't be a problem, especially if you are able to index into the set using row and column.